# keyboard sometimes doesnt type, sometimes types twice

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, typing

i'm having a weird problem on windows 10 where the keyboard has a bit of delay when typing, and sometimes doesnt work and sometimes it types twice in a row. This happens for all keys and on safe mode and in BIOS settings. Every keyboard I try does this, and they work fine on other computers. I'm sure its a driver problem or something similar, but I already uninstalled it and restarted my computer and nothing

and changing the typing delay settings on w10 keyboard settings makes no difference, like theres something overlapping with the windows settings

I also tried malwarebytes but it found nothing

any suggestions on what could be causing this?

Comment: If it happens in BIOS, then it's not an OS issue. But then the on-screen keyboard (if that's what you mean by virtual keyboard) is implemented strictly in the OS and shouldn't be affected. So it should be either this or that. Can you please double-check the on-screen keyboard and BIOS?

Comment: I found that the on screen keyboard is being affected by the mouse clicking twice, so It's not the same problem actually. Thanks for that

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the keyboard buffer. An easy way to check if it's a hardware issue, rather than OS, is to run from a bootable USB drive, e.g., Ubuntu, WinPE or Ultimate Boot CD. If that works without stuttering, then reinstall WIndows from ISO, keeping files... that should repair the issue.